# Edit x axis labels in visreg made with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the visreg package in R to visualize fits of models. The package has an option to make the plots using ggplot or base R. When I run the code with `gg=TRUE`, I cannot change things such as x axis tick labels. Whenever I try to use `scale_x_discrete` it gives me the error "Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale." Is it possible to replace the existing scale in ggplot with a custom scale (such as customized tick labels)?

For example:

```
library(visreg)
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
lm1 = lm(price~color + cut + carat, data = diamonds)
visreg(lm1, "cut", gg= TRUE)
```

If I were to do the following it would give me the error:

```
visreg(lm1, "cut", gg= TRUE)+scale_x_discrete(labels=c("F", "G", "VG", "P", "I"))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do so! Just added one!